# How can a man remove conceit?

Tags: maya

How can a man eliminate conceit (too much pride in yourself and your abilities and importance) ? Like Arjun though a good person , also favorite of Krishna died while trekking the Himalaya because he was pride that no one was better than him.

Comment: Pride can still have some value, not all so bad, rather curb conceit

Comment: Introspection by Contemplative Meditation, Complete surrender to the divine and requesting them to remove all your bad qualities....

Comment: One can overcome conceit by dosha darshana. (Causes of conceit , intellect body etc are temporal) . By analysing the doshas(faults) /shortcomings of possessing conceit , one may forfeit it.Also one is dependent on the contribution of several other beings, to accomplish every action. Therby the credits should be rightly shared with  the grand order of the world , that has supported it.

Comment: Some of the Advaita prakarana granthas, advocate dosha darshana, to come out of bad qualities